# DirectoryEntry.Invoke() throws error on "ChangePassword" call

Tags: c#, active-directory

`DirectoryEntryObject.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { oldPassword, newPassword } );` throws the following error:

> "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation.
>   ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0x80020005): Type mismatch.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005
>   (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Invoke(String
>   methodName, Object[] args)

Is this something to do with any settings in the AD or I am missing anything?

Comment: uses the "ChangePassword" function any ref-params?

Comment: @cevik, not sure If I understood the question. However, the it is called the following way:-

 userEntry.Invoke( "ChangePassword", new object[] { "MyOldPassword", "MyNewPassword" } );

Comment: What is the underlying class that you're actually talking to?

Comment: Are you running it as an admin or an account with enough priviledges to change account passwords?

Comment: @Lasse, check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa746340 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746341.

Comment: @w69rdy, good question. I need to see that. That said, ResetPassword using the same way works fine. I dont know if there is a difference.

Comment: Why is the new password parameter flagged with an [out] in the documentation? Won't that mean that you need to pass a ByRef value to the method? (I'm guessing here)

Comment: Have you tried just: `DirectoryEntryObject.Invoke("ChangePassword", oldPassword, newPassword);`, ie. without the array? I found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180915(VS.90).aspx

Comment: @Lasse - oops, looks like you commented as I was typing my answer, it seems we both found the same page on MSDN. It seems fairly conclusive from that page that the way we've both documented is the correct way! =)

Comment: @Lasse, @Rob, there is another MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invoke.aspx. And this Invoke() method takes object[]. This is used by  dew other applications in the company as well. I am not sure why this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an MSDN page titled [Managing User Passwords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180915%28VS.90%29.aspx) that has some examples of how to call `ChangePassword` from C#. The specific sample shows the following syntax:

```
usr.Invoke("ChangePassword", OldSecurelyStoredPassword, NewSecurelyStoredPassword);
```

I suspect it's because you're calling it and passing in an object array, rather than passing two strings explicitly (the documentation you've linked to in your comment indicates that it expects to be passed two strings, one as an input parameter and one as an output parameter. Try this:

```
var oldPassword = "TheOldPassword";
var newPassword = "TheNewPassword";
DirectoryEntryObject.Invoke("ChangePassword", oldPassword, newPassword);
```

Comment: there is another MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invoke.aspx. And this Invoke() method takes object[]. This is used by few other applications in the company as well. I am not sure why this won't work.

Comment: @Ashish, that's all well and good, but *have you tried what myself and Lasse have suggested?* AND, are you saying you have code in other applications that Invokes the **ChangePassword** method, passing in an object array and that *does* work?

Comment: "are you saying you have code in other applications that Invokes the ChangePassword method, passing in an object array and that does work?"

the answer is "yes".

Comment: And what about "have you tried what myself and Lasse have suggested?" ?

Comment: I will definitely give that a shot.

Comment: @Rob, I have the same issue and using two separate string parameters instead of an object[] does not help.

Comment: This was never mentioned, but the reason you pass two strings and not an array is that the `object[]` parameter in [`DirectoryEntry.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.invoke) is marked with the `params` keyword. If you look at the [documentation for the `params` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params), it should become clear. It is used to accept an unknown number of parameters.